# How to update a record by adding a number to pre-stored number in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let suppose in database i have a value 2300, and i want to add 200 to it, I have the following php script

```
$to_add = 200;
$query = mysqli_query("select * from table where id = '$row'");
$rec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$old_number = $rec['col'];
$new_number = $old_number + $to_add;
$query1 = mysqli_query("update table set col = '$new_number' where id = '$row' ");
```

My question is that can we done the above task with a single query like

```
$new_number = 200;
$query = mysqli_query("update table set col = 'pre_value + $new_number' where id = '$row' ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$new_number = 200;
$query = mysqli_query("update table set col = col + $new_number where id = '$row' ");
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also use shorthand assignment operator

```
$new_number = 200; $query = mysqli_query("update table set col +=
$new_number where id = '$row'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_number = 200;

update table set col = col + $new_number where id = '$row';
```